# Gaussian Mixture Model: bandwidth parameter versus variogram fitting?

Tags: covariance, gaussian-process, gaussian-mixture-distribution, variogram, geostatistics

I'm estimating a stationary, spatially random variable over a 2-dimensional domain.  I have ground-truth measurements in several locations, over time.

I need some way of spatially-interpolating between the measurements, obviously. I have identified two ways to do this, and I would like to know the trade-offs of each:

1)   use a variogram.  By dividing the data into training and testing, I can run the variogram on the training data to estimate which variogram is the best fit (gaussian, spherical, etc.), using root-mean square error.

2)   use a computational approach.  By implementing a gaussian process regression method with an isotropic gaussian covariance function of a given bandwidth.  Then, I can loop over bandwidth values, and for each bandwidth value, use a k-folds cross validation to observe the root-mean square error.  Then, I would select the bandwidth that yields the smallest root-mean square error.

Which approach is more favorable and why?  Of course, I could try both, but I'd like to gain some intuition around this problem since it comes up frequently.

Thank yo.

Answer (score 1):

Your approaches boil down to one single underlying model: a Gaussian random field with a second order stationary covariance. Bandwidth of 2) corresponds to the range of the variogram model; best fitting variogram model of 1) corresponds to the covariance function type of 2). How you exactly choose and evaluate the models and parameters is a different matter, unrelated to the choice between 1 and 2.

Comment: Welcome to our site, Edzer!